# how to sort a list in XSL

Tags: java, xslt

i'm developping a java application and using xsl. So i have a list that i want to display it with sort by modorder field

This is my code

```
<xsl:variable name="Vehicle" select="//portal:Portal/portal:Dictionary/portal:Vehicles/portal:Vehicle" />
<xsl:for-each select="$Vehicle">
    <tr>
        <xsl:variable name="vehname">
            <xsl:value-of select="@vehname" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <td style="background-color: #F2F2F2;">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('model-key', $vehname)">
                <xsl:variable name="model">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@model" />
                </xsl:variable>
                ....
                <td style="background-color: #F2F2F2;">
                    <table width="1140">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #F2F2F2; height:120px; width:120px;border-left: 1px solid #ddd;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$Model[@modname=$model]/@modorder" />
                            </td>
                            .....
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Try `xsl:sort select="key"` for sorting.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show a small example of the input, a complete stylesheet and the expected output - se: [mcve].